# I tried to create a def with more than two params

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I'm writing a Telegram bot, with Python-telegram-bot, my bot download a .mp3 from a podcast feed, and send it to the user, my problem is that I create a definition for the Download button but I need 3 params, and it's seems that Python just allow me two params per definition:

```
def button(update, context: CallbackContext, chat) -> None:

podcast = feedparser.parse('URL') 

file = podcast.entries[0].link

query = update.callback_query

if query.data == '1':

    wget.download(file, 'file.mp3')

    chat.send_audio(
        audio=open('file.mp3', 'rb')
    )
    
    os.unlink('file.mp3')
```

Well the response of Python interpreter is: chat argument is required. I don't understand cause I declare it in the def.

Comment: The error happens at the point where you try to _call_ the function, presumably with only two arguments.

Comment: But I added the 'chat' argument

Answer (score 1):

Chat is indeed declared in the def, but when calling your function- you haven't sent any argument to chat, and that is the problem.

Comment: The message error says: button () missing 1 required positional argument: 'chat'

Comment: Could you add the code the calls button()?

Comment: def button(update, context: CallbackContext, chat) ->

Comment: This is the declaration, not the actual using of the function, right?

Comment: Yes, where I need to specify the argument again?

Comment: I want you to show me the actual place you *called* button and sent parameters, apparently you've sent only 2... isn't it true?

Comment: dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))